# Parity getting started tutorial not working

Tags: dapp-development, parity, kovan, tutorials, manifest

I'm trying to do the getting started tutorial from Parity but it isn't working. When running the following command:

`parity --chain=kovan`

i get the following error message

`Cannot read manifest file at: "/Users/benjamin/Library/Application Support/io.parity.ethereum/dapps/mydappTest/manifest.json". Error: "Error { repr: Os { code: 2, message: \"No such file or directory\" } }"`

I'm using the standard manifest.json file, and when i go to localhost i can see the name of the dapp but when i click on it i get a `404 page not found.`

Somebody knows how to fix this?

thanks in advance

Comment: What's the output of `ls -l /Users/benjamin/Library/Application Support/io.parity.ethereum/dapps/mydappTest/` on a terminal?

Comment: It says the file doesn't exist. but when i go to `/Users/benjamin/Library/Application Support/io.parity.ethereum/dapps/mydappTest` it has all the files copied from github

Comment: Add to your question the output of "ls -l " as 5chdn has suggested. It might  be a read right issue.

Comment: this is the output: 
`-rw-r--r--    1 benjamin  staff  10255 19 mei 10:14 LICENSE
-rw-r--r--    1 benjamin  staff    194 19 mei 10:14 README.md
drwxr-xr-x    6 benjamin  staff    204 19 mei 10:18 dist
drwxr-xr-x  599 benjamin  staff  20366 19 mei 10:17 node_modules
-rw-r--r--    1 benjamin  staff   1594 19 mei 10:14 package.json
drwxr-xr-x    3 benjamin  staff    102 19 mei 10:14 src
-rw-r--r--    1 benjamin  staff    653 19 mei 10:14 webpack.config.js`